# How do I allow projects with different target platforms to depend on another shared project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a C# library project containing some shared code. Two other projects depend on this code. Project A can only target x86, because one of its dependencies is x86 only. Project B targets Any CPU (MSIL), because it will be used by other Any CPU code. I want Project B to remain Any CPU in order to be as flexible as possible, since it could be consumed by several other applications in the future.

Here is a simple dependency chart. All these projects reside in the same solution. I am currently using Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5.

```
     Project B C# (Any CPU)          Project A C# (x86)
               |                           |  |
               |---> Shared C# Code  <-----|  |------> Native Code (x86 only)
```

Is there any way I can have Visual Studio build both an Any CPU and x86 version of the shared code simultaneously and have the other projects depend on the correct version?

Comment: Your dependency chart isn't a chart at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make VS build different configurations of the same project *simultaneously* (it's also doubtful this would be beneficial). But the setup you describe is pretty basic and is typically solved by having seperate platform/configuration combinations (right-click solution->Configuration manager). For example (`--` means 'don't care'):

```
Release/AnyCPU
                       Build  Platform  Configuration
      SharedProject    x      AnyCPU    Release  
      ProjectA                --        --
      ProjectB         x      AnyCPU    Release 

Release/x86
                       Build  Platform  Configuration
      SharedProject    x      x86       Release  
      ProjectA         x      x86       Release 
      ProjectB                --        --
```

Eventually if you want to build more than one configuration with one click, look at Build->Batch Build.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that you could dictate whether a project gets built or not based on the platform selected at the solution level. While this still doesn't let me build everything all at once, I think it is close enough to what I need. Thanks!